# 2 step verification fears

Tags: google

My company have set up all of their shared work via Google apps. They are now insisting on everyone setting up two-step verification. I am a freelance and although they want me to share via Google, I have other Google accounts that are personal and for college that I can't risk losing access to. The main issue is with emails on my phone, but I'm worried about the whole safety of these personal accounts should I leave my firm/lose my phone. I understand they can just block accounts. Is there any way of separating the accounts out?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 step verification process does not affect all the accounts in the mobile. It would only ask for the account which is registered with the 2 step verification process.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create new account, only to use with the company and set two-step verification only for that account. They wouldn't be having any access or rights over any account other than that one whatsoever.
 Having a quick look trough the app, it gives me the option to add an account and not automatically do it for my primary android gmail account ...

Comment: I can confirm that: the procedure for setting up the two-factor authentication has been made complex for this same motive: forcing the user to pay attention. No account is automatically chosen, and the one you choose is the one that will be protected.